# Открыть проводник из браузера, с помощью js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, можно ли открыть проводник из браузера с заданным адресом каталога, с помощью js?
пробовал:

- window.open('file:\диск\каталог') - пишет not allowed to load local resource;
- window.showOpenFilePicker() - получается открыть, но путь нельзя указать или можно, но не нашел решения;

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: [file browser with specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264372/file-browser-with-specific-path)